# Using Try/catch with Do/While

Tags: php

this is more of a conceptual question.

Is it aceptable/good programming mixing do/while loops with try/catch?

ex:

```
<?php
function main() {

    $failure = 0;
    do {
       $failure += foo();
       $failure += bar();
       ...
       if ($failure) { return $failure; }
    } 
    while ($failure == 0);
}

function foo() {
    try {
        echo 'DO FOO STUFF<br />';
        return 0;
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) {
        return 1;
    }
}

function bar() {
    try {
        echo 'DO BAR STUFF<br />';
        return 0;
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) {
        return 1;
    }
}
?>
```

The reason I'm asking is that I read somewhere that mixing both is bad practice. You should create your own exceptions and "throw" them instead. But isn't that a bit of an overkill?

EDIT:
To explain the scenario where this question emerged, imagine a robot that has to follow a line. The robot calculates its position (X position, Y poistion, Z position and "postural" position) everytime he takes a step and sends the information to a server. Server doublechecks this information. If any anomaly is found, servers sends a "stop" signal to the robot. The robot stops, recalculates its position, resends information and waits for a "go" signal.

This loop example was based on the data feed received from the robot. If something went wrong, (like a broken wireless link, or an obstacle, or a misstep) the robot must stop to prevent going astray, or falling, or anything. We aren't interested in knowing what went wrong, or why it went wrong, just that it went wrong (or not). (that is actually taken care in another part of the code, not PHP based, the Debug Module).

EDIT 2:
Like everyone pointed out, seems the right approach is to properly raise/handle the exceptions.
Since everyone seems to agree in this, I don't know who to award the "right answer" tick.
I will wait a few days and give it to the one with more votes if that's ok!

Comment: sorry to be off-topic but 'return' in a loop isn't a good choice.

Comment: nah! All input is good if it's constructive. Btw, why is it bad to return from a loop? Would it be better to goto?

Comment: In your example above, it will never check the condition while() since everything is returned before, in do{}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to avoid mixing `try/catch` with `do/while`.

But the example you give has less problems with `do/while` and more with swallowing exceptions in the `try/catch` block.

Catching the base exception type and swallowing it is a bad practice in any language, PHP or otherwise.  It is best to only catch specific exception types, and let the rest fall through the catch block.

For example, if you were accessing a file, and caught the `FileNotFound` exception (if there is such a thing in PHP), that would be OK.

But if you catch all exception types, then you're going to catch things like `OutOfMemoryException`.  This would be fine, if you properly handled it, and made sure it wasn't going to throw again.  But in your case, you're probably not "doing the right thing" for that case, so you should just let it fall through.

The reason you don't want to eat exceptions (without logging them) is that you won't be able to debug your code if it ever goes to a locked down production environment.  If the exception is caught, then the user will just see buggy behavior, and won't be able to file a bug report that gives you enough information to debug it.  They might be able to give you repro steps, but that is pretty unreliable.  This is also pretty much worthless for an intermittant problem.

If you eat the exception, you're basically throwing away the most useful data there is for debugging.

Things that make this less true:

- Sometimes in top-level web code, you will want to catch the exception, log it, then swallow it so the user doesn't see it (but return from the function, so you don't execute more code while in a buggy state).  This makes it so the user doesn't see revealing information about your code (the stack trace).
- If the language you are doing exception handling in has poor support for exceptions, and doesn't have derived exception types.  I don't know a lot about PHP, so this may or may not be true in this language.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to swallow the exceptions and just report the failure then this is okay.  You'll have to do something like

```
   $failure &= bar();
```

though, or you'll lose the failure condition of foo().

If you want to be able to act on the exception further up the call stack then you're better off leaving it alone, or at least rethrowing it, so you can catch it where you want to handle it.

Comment: yes, I was simplifying the code and created something without any sense =P

Answer (score 1):

There is no general reason to avoid using try/catch within functions called inside a do/while loop.

Depending upon what you are actually doing inside the loop you have the option of catching exceptions inside the loop, and exiting on an error condition returned, or wrapping the whole while loop in a try/catch block.

You should decide how to do it in any specific case according to what the exceptions mean for your code:

- Can the exception be recovered from?
- What action needs to be taken in response to an exception being thrown?
- What state should your program be left in after a particular exception has been thrown and handled?

In your example, `bar()` will be executed even if `foo()` generates an error. This may or may not be what you want. Catching exceptions outside the loop would not allow this option.
Also, the loop won't terminate when `bar()` returns `false` if `foo()` subsequently returns `true` - this is probably a bug. Catching any exceptions outside the loop would mean the loop would be terminated at the point of error. Again, this may or may not be desirable depending on your application.

Also, it is likely that different exceptions need to be handled in different ways. Importantly, if you catch the base exception type, rather than a more specific derived type you are losing the ability to do this. Catching more specific exceptions (including custom exceptions) will help you:

- Make sure you are not
  accidentally swallowing unexpected
  exceptions you didn't mean to catch.
- Have multiple different error
  scenarios handled by the same catch
  block (by throwing the same custom
  exception for each of those error
  scenarios).

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. This code is based on a RL situation where a robot follows a line in the floor and is constantly giving feedback to a server. Server processes a lot of information like robot absolute position, relative position, distance to GOAL, etc... but only for process checking. The response it gives to the robot is actually 0 or 1, that is, proceed or stop. So any exception thrown in the process means data will not be viable and/or recoverable and the process has to start again, that is, the robot has to "rethink" where he is and how to reach GOAL.

Comment: This particular piece of code refers to file upload and streaming. If the wireless to the robot is cut for some reason, file uploading is interrupted resulting in an incomplete/corrrupted file. Since data is created on the fly and can't be recreated, we cannot ask for a "retry" (and we didn't want to anyway =P) so we cannot recover from the error. The robot must stop, rethink and ask for permission to move again.

Comment: Yes, but beware that since you are catching the base Exception type (instead of a derived one) you may also catch exceptions that the whole process cannot recover from (not just the current stage or iteration). This is why it is *always* better to catch specific exception that you can handle gracefully, and let others bubble up to a higher level. I've made a minor edit to my answer to emphasise that point.